# SQL Server : index for finding latest value which is greater than a passed value

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing

I have a table with 4 columns

- USER_ID: numeric
- EVENT_DATE: date
- VERSION: date
- SCORE: decimal

I have a clustered index on (`USER_ID, EVENT_DATE, VERSION`). These three values together are unique.

I need to get the maximum `EventDate` for a set of `UserId`s (~1000 different ids) where the `Score` is larger than a specific value and only consider those entries with a specific `Version`.

```
SELECT M.*
FROM (VALUES 
        (   5237    ),
        ………1000 more
        (   27054   ) ) C (USER_ID)
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP 1 C.USER_ID, M.EVENT_DATE, M.SCORE
     FROM MY_HUGE_TABLE M                   
     WHERE C. USER_ID = M. USER_ID 
       AND M.VERSION = 'xxxx-xx-xx' 
       AND M.SCORE > 2 --Comment M.SCORE > 2
     ORDER BY M.EVENT_DATE DESC) M
```

Once I execute the query, I get poor results with respect to runtime, due to a missing index on score column (I suppose).

If I delete the filtering on “M.SCORE > 2” I get my results ten times faster, nevertheless the latest Scores may be less than “2”.

Could anyone please hint me on how to setup an index which could allow me to improve my query performance.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: If version is not very selective, and you always pick a particular one, a filtered index really gives it a kick in the pants

Answer (score 1):

For your query, the optimal index would be on `(User_ID, Version, ValueDate desc, Score)`.

Unfortunately, your clustered index doesn't match.  Only the first and third columns match, but they need to match in order.  So, only the `User_ID` can help but that probably doesn't do much to filter the data.

Comment: Hi Gordon, sry i made some typo in my example code. I confused ValueDate with EVENT_DATE.

Comment: Does it make any sense to add my "SCORE" Column to an index for this purpose? Because (USER_ID, VERSION, EVENT_DATE, SCORE) doesnt seem to be fitting as there may only be overhead as eauch EVENT_DATE only has one SCORE

Comment: @user2989815 . . . Yes.  I think I was confused on whether you wanted that filter in or not.  Your question is clear; it was my confusion.